# Match Dataframe rows on signature with tolerance interval

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["DATE","QTY1", "QTY2", "ID", "CODE"])
df1["DATE"] = ["2000-05-01", "2000-05-03", "2001-01-15", "2001-02-20", "2001-02-22"]
df1["QTY1"] = [10, 11, 12,5,4]
df1["QTY2"] = [100, 101, 102,15,14]
df1["ID"] = [1,2,3,4,5]
df1["CODE"] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["DATE","QTY1", "QTY2", "ID", "CODE"])
df2["DATE"] = ["2000-05-02", "2000-05-04", "2001-01-12", "2001-03-28", "2001-08-21", "2005-07-01"]
df2["QTY1"] = [9, 101, 11,5.1,100, 10]
df2["QTY2"] = [99, 12, 1000,6,3, 1]
df2["ID"] = [1,2,3,8,5, 9]
df2["CODE"] = ["F", "G", "H", "I", "L", "M"]

df1:
   DATE          QTY1  QTY2  ID CODE
0  2000-05-01    10   100   1    A
1  2000-05-03    11   101   2    B
2  2001-01-15    12   102   3    C
3  2001-02-20     5    15   4    D
4  2001-02-22     4    14   5    E

df2
   DATE          QTY1  QTY2  ID CODE
0  2000-05-02    9.0    99   1    F
1  2000-05-04  101.0    12   2    G
2  2001-01-12   11.0  1000   3    H
3  2001-03-28    5.1     6   8    I
4  2001-08-21  100.0     3   5    L
5  2005-07-01     10     1   9    M
```

My goal is to create a signature with some tolerance for each row and match rows on both DF that fall in such interval.
The signature for each row is structure as follow:

- DATE (with tolerance of +/- 5 days)
- Qty1 (with tolerance of 10%)
- Qty2 (with tolerance of 10%)
- ID (perfect match).

So for example the matching result for the above DFs will return the following rows (the first line from each DF) grouped by signature:

```
Signature1    2000-05-01    10   100   1     A
              2000-05-02    9.0    99   1    F
```

All the others rows do not respect one or more tolerances.

Currently I am doing that with a classical for loop using iterrows() and checking all fields but for large DFs performances are quite poor.
I was wondering if there is a more pandas-like approach that could help me to speed it up.
Thanks